How to get full page screenshot in android useng appium and nodejs
I need help to creating fullpage screenshot in Android automation. I'm using nodejs and appium for this.
I tried to take screesnhot, append it to array, then scroll down, take another screesnhot, append in to array etc. At the end i use the library merge-base64 to merge it. But it takes quite a long time. and there are gluing artifacts in the screenshot. Maybe there is an easier and faster way?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
